# Can I use the term "ageographical" to refer to multinational corporations?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I came across the following sentence and checked it in the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

> Ideologues, be they left or right politically, are fundamentally
>   ageographical.

I know that the a- negative prefix is from Greek, and appears only on Greek roots, but the word is the COCA.

So, can I use the word 'ageographical' this way in an PhD essay I'm writing?

> Multinational corporations, be they based in Europe or America, are
>   fundamentally ageographical.

Or is there a better word/phrase?

Comment: Impossible to not read age o graphical. Perhaps a-geographical will help

Comment: I read that as *areographical*: pertaining to the physical features of the planet Mars.

Answer (score 2):

It is as well formed as apolitical, so why not, meaning : not relative to a geographical description (for instance, the Genesis is such : nobody knows where the Paradise was supposed to be).

But I guess that the meanings are :
- The politician are not parochial ;
- The corporations are international, above the boarders.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them **transnational**.

The word *geographical* normally have these meanings:

> 1. Of or relating to geography.
> 2. Concerning the topography of a specific region.

As I can imagine, *ageographical* would mean either *not related to geography* or *not concerning the topography of a specific region*, neither of which is your intended meaning.

**EDIT:** *Trans* means *across* and one of the meanings of the latter is *spanning*. The corporations' business extends over nations, hence is transnational and so are they.